# Where MapReduce History Server stores its data?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

Based on the documentation: [MapReduce History Server API](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs/HistoryServerRest.html),
I can get all the information using different REST calls.

Does anyone know where that data is originally stored/read from by History Server? Also what format is that in?

Answer (score 1):

It stores the data in HDFS. It will be under /user/history/done and owned by mapred in Cloudera and Hortonworks distributions.

We can also provide custom locations using parameters `mapreduce.jobhistory.done-dir` and `mapreduce.jobhistory.intermediate-done-dir`.